# Drawing and storing a user's touch path in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm struggling with something I would expect to be straight forward with libgdx.

In short this is a "finger paint" app where I want to draw a path of a certain width where the user touches the screen.

I've earlier done this by using a plain Android `android.view.View`. I had a `android.graphics.Path` in which I stored the coordinates of the user's current touch. In the `onDraw()` method of the view I drew the path to the `android.graphics.Canvas`. Whenever the user released a finger I drew the path to an offline canvas/`android.graphics.Bitmap` which also was drawn in the `onDraw()` method. Plain and simple.

How can that be done using libgdx?

I have tried using a `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap` that I can draw a line to whenever the user moves a finger. This works well except the fact that I'm unable to control the witdh of the line using `Gdx.gl.glLineWidth()`. I know I can draw a rectangle instead of a line to set the width, but Pixmap doesn't seem to have any means of rotating, so I don't see how this can be done.

I can use a `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer` for drawing lines (or rectangles) in `com.badlogic.gdx.Screen.render()`. As far as I can see I then need to store every single touch point of the current touch, and then draw all lines on render. Whenever the user relases a finger I guess I can store the screen as-is with something like `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap()`. Hopefully there is a easier way to achieve what I want.

Comment: In HTML5 one would use a canvas with an appropriate composite mode. Maybe libgdx has a similar feature.

Comment: I haven't found that feature in libgdx, but yes, that would've worked great in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up drawing circles on a pixmap where the line should be:

- One circle on touchDown
- Several circles from last touch point to next touch point reported to touchDragged

I'm not very happy with this solution, but it kinda works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can calculate line dot coordinates manually and use triangles to draw them on pixmap? Like use 2 triangles to form (rotated) box?

Comment: But does the pixmap support drawing triangles?

Comment: I think so: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#fillTriangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Heh, sorry. Can't believe I missed that earlier today when I looked for it. I'll check it out and see how it goes. It should be good match.